# Program won't print out the intersection or difference! Any suggestions?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class setPractice {
    public static Scanner kbd;

    public static final int MAXSIZE = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] setA = new int[MAXSIZE];
        int[] setB = new int[MAXSIZE];
        int[] intersect = new int[MAXSIZE];
        int[] difference = new int[MAXSIZE];
        int sizeA, sizeB, interSize, diffSize;

        System.out.print("How many numbers will be in the 1st set: ");
        sizeA = kbd.nextInt();
        while (sizeA > MAXSIZE) {
            System.out
                    .print("Error: Set size is too large. Re-enter set size: ");
            sizeA = kbd.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter list of integers for 1st set: ");
        getData(setA, sizeA);
        sort(setA, sizeA);
        System.out.println("The ascending order for 1st is:");
        print(setA, sizeA);

        System.out.print("How many numbers will be in the 2nd set: ");
        sizeB = kbd.nextInt();
        while (sizeB > MAXSIZE) {
            System.out
                    .print("Error: Set size is too large. Re-enter set size: ");
            sizeB = kbd.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter list of integers for 2nd set: ");
        getData(setB, sizeB);
        sort(setB, sizeB);
        System.out.println("The ascending order for the 2nd set  is:");
        print(setB, sizeB);

        interSize = intersection(setA, setB, sizeA, sizeB, intersect);
        System.out.print("The intersection of the two sets is: ");
        for (int x = 0; x < interSize; x++) {
            System.out.print(intersect[x] + " ");
        }

        diffSize = difference(setA, sizeA, setB, sizeB, intersect);
        System.out.print("\n\nThe difference of A-B is: ");
        for (int x = 0; x < diffSize; x++) {
            System.out.print(difference[x] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void getData(int[] set, int size) {

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            int num = kbd.nextInt();
            int count = search(set, size, num);
            if (count == 0)
                set[x] = num;
            else
                x--;
        }
    }

    public static int search(int[] set, int size, int num) {

        int count = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            if (num == set[x])
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static int difference(int[] setA, int sizeA, int[] setB, int sizeB,
            int[] resultSet) {

        int y = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++) {
            int num = setA[x];
            int found = search(setB, sizeB, num);
            if (found == 0) {
                resultSet[y] = num;
                y++;
            }
        }
        return y;
    }

    public static void sort(int[] nums, int size) {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length - i - 1; j++) {
                if (nums[j] > nums[j + 1]) {
                    temp = nums[j];
                    nums[j] = nums[j + 1];
                    nums[j + 1] = temp;

                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void print(int[] nums, int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] != 0) {
                System.out.println(nums[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int intersection(int[] setA, int[] setB, int size, int sizeB,
            int[] resultSet) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < setA.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < setB.length; j++) {
                if (setA[i] == setB[j]) {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        resultSet = new int[count];
        count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < setA.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < setB.length; j++) {
                if (setA[i] == setB[j]) {
                    resultSet[count++] = setA[i];
                    break;
                }


            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

The requirements are that I must use methods and loops to reach the solution. Also the intersection and difference methods MUST return an int as part of the assignment instructions!

#### Test Input:

```
How many numbers will be in the 1st set: 3
Enter list of integers for 1st set: 
34
2
56

The ascending order for 1st is:
2
34
56

How many numbers will be in the 2nd set: 4
Enter list of integers for 2nd set: 
56
2
33
6

The ascending order for the 2nd set  is:
2
6
33
56

The intersection of the two sets is: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

The difference of A-B is:
```

Comment: And you cannot use something like java.util.Set, can you?

Comment: There's quite a lot of code here, and I don't see anything obviously wrong.  I think you should write some static test methods and invoke them from main (or a separate test class).  That should allow you (and us) to narrow down the cases where the intersection and difference aren't working.

Comment: Are intersection AND difference wrong??? Difference looks ok to me.

Comment: I think I see a pretty obvious indexing error in difference(), but it's hard to be sure.

Comment: I actually did try that and for the intersection it keeps printing out 0's and for the difference it does not print out anything!

Comment: Well, show us the test code and its output so we can have a better idea what is not working.

Comment: Edit on the post: test input added

Comment: you need to use the debugger

Answer (score 1):

I think i found your errors:

1. You use `set.length` (or `setA.length` or ...) instead of the method parameter (`size` or `sizeA` or ...) multiple times.

   Especially in your `sort` method this is problematic: the sorted arrays will start with `0`s. You don't recognize this, since you ignore `0`s in your `print` method. Print it the way you print the intersection and difference and you'll see the error.
2. You pass `intersect` as parameter to your `difference` method instead of `difference`.
3. You create a new array in your `intersection` method. This replaces only the local array, not the one created in your `main` method. (`int` arrays are initialized with `0`s)

Comment: Thanks you so much! Also just to clarify-arent arrays supposed to be sorted beginning with 0?

Comment: @user3546001: The `0`s are the "palces in your set" that you didn't fill. *IF* you want them at the beginning, then you need to make changes to the rest of the code. You are also ignoring ALL `0`s in your `print` method. However `0` may be in one of your sets. If you get the index ranges right, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Another quick question-since you specified that the new array will not be replacing the array in the main method-how do you think i should solve this problem? Since the method is supposed to be returning an int and its supposed to be printing out the intersection?

Comment: @user3546001: If you send something as a parameter to a method, a "new variable" is created in the scope of the method. That means as soon as you create a new array, `intersect` in the `main` method and `resultSet` no longer refer to the same object. As long as you don't replace the reference however, you can still modify the elements of the array and the changes will be visible in the calling method. So just fill the `resultSet` that was passed to the method with the results and don't create a new one.

Comment: Okay! also do you have any suggestions on how to print the sort  method without using the print method?

Comment: @user3546001: Wait... Print the method or print the filled array. Printing the method does not make much sense and why print the filled array without the `print` method when you just have to change a few things to make it work? BTW, you already wrote the correct code for printing a array, just not line by line.